# get day difference between two date using carbon

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-4, php-carbon

I am using laravel and carbon package.I have two date. Now I want to get date difference from my given date.

```
$start_Date='2016-06-02 18:00:13';
$end_Date='2016-06-06 18:00:13';
$start = Carbon::parse($start_Date);
$end = Carbon::parse($end_Date);
$now = Carbon::now();
$length = $start->diffInDays($now);
$lengthFromEnd = $end->diffInDays($now);
```

if `now() == 2016-06-07` then

**$length**  will be `5 days` and

**$lengthFromEnd** will be `-1 days`.

but my code return abnormal result

Comment: What is the "abnormal result"?

Comment: What result is your code return?

Comment: not correct day count return @CSchulz

Comment: @HashibulHasan what is the day count you have right now?

Comment: its return 10 for -1 days @weigreen

Comment: Try `diff()` instead of `diffInDays` and `print_r/dd` that object you'll get your answer

Comment: Its showing me `$length = 4` and `$lengthFromEnd = 0`

Comment: Please share more details, like the code that returns this "abnormal result"

Answer (score 6):

you can also try this way.

```
$difference = $start_date->diff($end_date)->days;
```

Answer (score 5):

For negative result, you need a add parameter, like this:

```
$absolute = false;
$end->diffInDays($now, $absolute);
```

Answer (score 1):

This usually works perfectly but recently I had faced some problems finding the difference between to date where my date format was
 `12-02-2020`

```
$endDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $data['enddate']);
$left = Carbon::parse(Carbon::now())->floatDiffInDays($endDate, false);
```

If the date is expired then `$left` will be negative and number of days it has passed otherwise it will be a positive number

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. Only problem is you are getting *unexpected* results.

When you said `now() == 2016-06-07`, you forgot to consider the time. Actually, `now` must be something like this `2016-06-07 15:47:47`.

Since,

```
$start_Date='2016-06-02 18:00:13';
$end_Date='2016-06-06 18:00:13';
```

you will get `$length = 4` and `$lengthFromEnd = 0`.
When the `$now` becomes `2016-06-07 18:00:13`, then you'll get `$length = 5` and `$lengthFromEnd = 1`.

Note that you won't get `$lengthFromEnd = -1` as Carbon gives difference in positive numbers.