# How to calculate a few days left or the last few days in Carbon

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5, php-carbon

I have `ExpireDate`, `NowTime` fields in my table like example:

```
Expire Date : 2020-05-11 00:00:00
NowTime :     2020-05-13 00:00:00
```

I want to get to the difference between the two dates (`NowTime` - `ExpireDate`) and use this code:

```
$diff=Carbon::now()->diffInDays($row->expire_date);
```

The problem is that if there are two days left until the expiration date, Carbon return **2**,  Also, if 2 days have passed since the date Carbon return **2**

How can I detect if it's 2 days left or 2 days passed of date?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/51001799/1213708, may do what you are after.

Comment: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ search for `diffindays`; as the linked question shows you need to use the 2nd parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following tools:

```
Carbon::now()->diffInDays($row->expire_date, false) // negative number if expired_date is over
Carbon::now()->isAfter($row->expire_date) // true if expired_date is over
```

Answer (score 2):

Laravel 5.*, you just try diffForHumans() method. It's no needed to the current date. The result will be display second, minutes, hour, week, month, year ago.

```
$diff = $row->expire_date->diffForHumans();

echo $row->expire_date->diffForHumans(); // a second ago 
echo $row->expire_date->diffForHumans(); // 10 hour ago
echo $row->expire_date->diffForHumans(); // 5 days ago
echo $row->expire_date->diffForHumans(); // 1 week ago
echo $row->expire_date->diffForHumans(); // 4 month ago
echo $row->expire_date->diffForHumans(); // 2 year ago
```

If you need to use Carbon method try this..

```
{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($row->expire_date)->diffForHumans()}}
```